# How to efficiently check whether an element is within a range of a reference list and get the index reference list?

Tags: python, list, performance

The idea is to check whether each element in a list (i.e., `data_list`) is within a range of a reference list (i.e., `range_list`). If it is within the ref list, then extract at which index  of the reference list (`range_list`) it occur.

The following code were drafted.

```
    lst=range(0,1000,1)
    n=6
    range_list=[lst [i:i + n] for i in range ( 0, len ( lst ), n )]

    data_list=[1,2,5,6,8,10,12,100, 102, 104, 105]
    idx_un=[]
    for x in data_list:
        for idx,y in enumerate(range_list):
            if min(y)<= x <= max ( y ):
                idx_un.append(idx)
                break
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 16, 17, 17, 17]
```

But I am curious whether there exist much more compact and efficient approach.

Comment: Will your `range_list` always be a sorted list of adjacent ranges, as in your example, or could it be anything?

Comment: Thanks for dropping by @Mark. `range_list`  it is as in the example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your ranges is basically a partition of the integers, you don't really need a list of ranges. You can just use a list of starting numbers of the ranges. Once you do that, you can can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module to get blazing fast binary search operations — both faster *and* simpler (assuming it fits your use case). That would leave you with something like:

```
import bisect

range_list = list(range(n,1000, n))
data_list=[1,2,5,6,8,10,12,100, 102, 104, 105]

[bisect.bisect_right(range_list, n) for n in data_list]
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 16, 17, 17, 17]
```

Comment: Thanks for the `bisect`, new lib for me